# Using compass + blueprint in rails. How to get visual grid overlay

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I am sure I saw at one point a technique to overlay a grid on top of the page when using blueprint + compass. Any idea on how to turn this on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put  `<div class="container showgrid">`  in your "main" html page/layout

Answer (score 3):

Don't do what's suggested on the answer, that's the incorrect way to do it.

The goal of sass is to **avoid** adding presentation stuff to your `html`.

Inside your `sass` or `.scss` file do a `+showgrid` or a `@include showgrid`.

Comment: I agree, but what I meant is "showgrid" is strictly a metter of CSS class inside screen.css, which is part of blueprint no metter which way you use to dinamically compile that. Add a grid, is a core "function" of blueprint not of commpass. May be my answer respond to just half a question.

Comment: @Lucas agreed. Compass contains stuff that helps when working with Blueprint to adapt to the SASS Paradigm. In any case good answer; what I added here is just a "FYI" for the people who reach to this via Google. :)